# what is the asp.net controller for input

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know the asp.net controller for input html

Comment: "Least Detailed Question of the Week" goes to...

Comment: @kehrk sorry didin't understand your point. there is no "Least Detailed" controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you want to input. The simplest is the textbox http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx